# How could I run a single line of code (not script) from command prompt?

Tags: command-line, cmd

Simple question here, just can't seem to pass it google in a way it can understand.

Say I wanted to execute a line of actual programming code (c++ or java or python... etc) like SetCursorPos or printf from the command prompt command line. I vaguely imagine I would have to invoke the compiler and pass the command to it like a parameter, where from it would then be converted into machine language and passed to... where exactly?

Okay so that was kind of two questions.

1. How to run actual code from the command line and
2. what exactly is happening when a fully compiled program, or converted line of code (presuming these are essentially binary containers at that point), is executed?

Question one takes priority obviously. Unfortunately, I can not find any documentation on it, just a bunch of stuff vaguely related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to run actual code from the command line

Without delving into the vast amounts of blurriness between them, there are two major categories of language implementations: interpreters and compilers.

With many interpreters (or implementations with implicit compilation, such as V8 JavaScript's [jit](/questions/tagged/jit) compiler, or pretty much anything with a [repl](/questions/tagged/repl)), running a single line from the command line should be fairly trivial. CPython (the standard implementation of Python) has the `-c command` option:

```
$ python -c 'print("Hello, world!")'
Hello, world!
```

Language implementations with explicit compilation steps will tend to be decidedly less simple. In particular, the compiler would need to either accept source either from directly out of the argument list, or from standard input (via piping or redirection). On the output side, your compiler would have to support immediately executing that program, or outputting it to standard out, so that an operating system feature (if it exists) can execute it from a pipe.

To my knowledge, most explicit compilers are not designed with such usage in mind. In such cases, your best bet is to see if there is a REPL available for the language in question, preferably one as compatible with your compiler as possible, or to create (or find) a wrapper that makes it look like your language has a REPL. The wrapper would:

1. Accept input along the lines of CPython above.
2. Create a temporary source file behind the scenes with the code to be run and any necessary boilerplate.
3. Pass that file to the compiler.
4. Automatically run the resulting executable.
5. Delete the source file and executable. These may be cleaned up by the operating system later instead, if they're in a temp directory.

From the point of view of the user, this *should* look pretty similar to the CPython example, as they wouldn't have to interact with or see the compiler or temporary files.